# Delphi record copy constructor

Tags: delphi

Look at this code:

```
type
 TTest = record
  a: integer;
  pa: PInteger;
 end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a, b: ttest;
begin

 memo1.Clear;

 a.a := 5;
 a.pa := @a.a;

 Memo1.Lines.Add(a.a.ToString + ' - ' + (a.pa)^.ToString);

 b := a;
 b.a := 8;

 Memo1.Lines.Add(b.a.ToString + ' - ' + (b.pa)^.ToString);

end;
```

The output is the following:

```
5 - 5
8 - 5
```

That is correct but not what I expect. When I say `b := a` it copies each field of a into b. So given that `a.pa := @a.a;` of course `b.pa` will be the same as `a.pa`.

Instead I want that once I call `b := a` the `b.pa` points to `b.a` and not to `a.a`. How can I do this? The output would be

```
5 - 5
8 - 8
```

In C++ there is the (deep) copy constructor that can fix this issue. In delphi it's a different scenario but is there something "equivalent"? I have seen the operator overload list in the doc but I wasn't able to find the proper one.

Comment: I'm not sure that deep copy would help in this example.

Comment: I guess that in c++ terms this would be more a deep assignment instead of a deep copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something "equivalent"?

No. You'd have to write you own function or method, and call it explicitly.

Comment: Well something like b.Copy(a) was what I wanted to avoid but it seems to be the only solution. Could a record constructor help or that wouldn't be possible anyway?

Comment: You'd have to call it

Comment: Still an explicit call. Ok got it, I'll go for what you've suggested me in the answers

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but maybe a function can help. Copy works as you expected and initialization of **pa** is not needed. The limitation is, you can't set **pa** anymore.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
 TTest = record
  a: integer;
  function pa: PInteger;
 end;

var a, b: TTest;

function TTest.pa: PInteger;
begin
  Result := @a;
end;

begin
 a.a := 5;
// a.pa := @a.a; <- this is not needed anymore but also not possible

 WriteLn(IntToStr(a.a) + ' - ' + IntToStr((a.pa)^));

 b := a;
 b.a := 8;

 WriteLn(IntToStr(b.a) + ' - ' + IntToStr((b.pa)^));
 ReadLn;
end.
```